# Using strncat method on arduino outputs an erroneous value

Tags: c++, string, arduino, string-concatenation

I need to decode and send a GPS signal to a remote server using a GSM module. I generated Latitude and Longitude values separately and concatenated into a `char` array. So I can easily pass a `char*` to the GSM modules serial `write()` method. But those concatenated string contains erroneous values. I checked for the decoded values and they have real numbers but this only happens as I concatenate it into my `char` array. I run this code on an Arduino Uno:

```
void loop()
{
  char data[128];
  data[0]='\0';
  initialize();

  strncat(data,getLat(),10);
  strncat(data," ",2);
  strncat(data,getLon(),10);

  Serial.write(data);
  Serial.println();

}

char* getLat(){
  char buffer[10];
  dtostrf(flat, 3, 6, buffer);
  Serial.write(buffer);
  Serial.print(" ");
  return buffer;
}
```

**Output** looks like this: first two columns has the values just printed when `getLat()` methods are called (There are no errors in the conversion) and last two values are the concatenated part.

```
 6.929772 79.947296    Àb 79.947296
 6.929772 79.947296    6.929772 79.947296
 6.929772 79.947296    6.929772 79.947296
 6.929772 79.947296    6.929772 79.947296
 6.929772 79.947296    6.929772 79tdt
 6.929772 79.947296    6.929772 79.947296
 6.929772 79.947296    6.vtet bztbt
 6.929772 79.947296    6.929772 79.947296
```

Can someone tell me what is wrong here? Thank you in advance.

Comment: `getLat()` returns the address of an automatic variable. That address is no longer valid once the function returns, and any dereference or even eval of that address invokes *undefined behavior*.

Comment: I declared the buffer as a heap variable. Now it seems okay. 
thank you!

Comment: Hope you used a smart pointer. Best of luck.

Comment: I am not very experienced with pointers. I will go through the internet to learn best practices. If you have any suggestions I would be pleased to hear.

Comment: You're doing fine, and taking self-initiative is important. Do some searching on *this* side for C++ smart pointers. The *best* reference on C++11 and its offerings can be found at [cppreference.com](http://www.cppreference.com). If you spend 30-60min per day reading about something new to you on that site, then working with what you learned in small sample programs, your skills will flourish. spend time with their samples. its worth it, believe me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you change your code to a practical and simple 'helloworld.cpp' file and compile it with a GNU C++ compiler, you are warned about the problem with how you are currently returning a pointer to something on the heap that gets destroyed when getLat() goes out of scope:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

char* getLat();

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    char test[20] = {0};
    strncpy(test,getLat(),10);
    fprintf(stdout, "%s\n", test);
    return 1;
}

char* getLat(){
  char buffer[10] = {0};
  memset(buffer,0,sizeof(buffer));
  strcpy(buffer, "Testycole");
  // dtostrf(flat, 3, 6, buffer);
  // Serial.write(buffer);
  // Serial.print(" ");
  return buffer;
}
```

---

Compiling:

```
$ g++ file.cpp 
file.cpp: In function ‘char* getLat()’:
file.cpp:16:8: warning: address of local variable ‘buffer’ returned [-Wreturn-local-addr]
   char buffer[10] = {0};
```

---

At runtime, I see garbage:

```
$ a.out
 ��
```

---

A quick fix, but not necessarily the best fix, is to allocate the buffer variable on the heap instead of within the scope of getLat().  Change GetLat() code like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

char* getLat();

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    char test[20] = {0};
    char *heapBuffer = getLat();
    strncpy(test,heapBuffer,10);
    fprintf(stdout, "%s\n", test);
    //delete[] heapBuffer; // C++ deallocation; prevents memory leak.
    free(heapBuffer);    // C deallocation; prevents memory leak.

    return 1;
}


char* getLat(){
  //char *buffer = new char[10]; // C++ allocation
  char *buffer = (char*)malloc(10); // C allocation - to be a C purist.

  memset(buffer,0,sizeof(buffer));
  strcpy(buffer, "Testycole");
  // dtostrf(flat, 3, 6, buffer);
  // Serial.write(buffer);
  // Serial.print(" ");
  return buffer;
}
```

...this yields better results:

```
$ a.out
Testycole
```

Don't forget that you have to deallocate the heap memory storing the char[10] buffer object after you finish with it, or you have yourself a memory leak. :-)